# Unusual JavaScript for loop scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Arriving at JavaScript from a C# and Java background, I am surprised to see the below snippet of code works. The variable `s` as I return it from the `sum` function should not exist in this scope.

How does JavaScript scope work in the following example? The scope of `s` should be limited to inside the `for` loop but not after its closing curly bracket. The equivalent snippet in Java or C# will state something like *s does not exist in the current context*.

```js
function sum(arr) {
    for(var i = 0, s = 0; i < arr.length; s += arr[i++]) {
        // scope of s is okay here
    }
    return s; // but, shouldn't this be a violation of scope?
}

// some test code
var data = [1,2,3,4];
var total = sum(data);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Also, [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Thanks - it's the *No such thing as block scope in JavaScript* part that got me.

Comment: The problem with the accepted duplicate answer is its lack of explanations, but the example tells me why it works the way it does. I can't explain it in language terminology, but I get how it works now.

Comment: See also Hoisting - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var